# Python implementation of Determining DNA Health algorithm from HackerRank

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, computer-science

I am trying to solve [**Determining DNA Health** challenge from Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/determining-dna-health/problem) using python. (I have to add I am somewhat new to python 3. Still learning the language)

My solution fails for test cases 7, 8 and 9 with a message reading "Wrong Answer".

When I run the following code locally, I can confirm that for these test cases my implementation produces the expected output.

I am wondering what would be the problem.

I am a bit puzzled at the moment. Is there a problem with my implementation? If so how come it produces correct answers for 28 test cases but fails on these 3? Or is it a misleading/confusing result message from Hacker Rank, as I happen to know that people find these 3 test cases (7, 8 and 9) problematic from what I learnt from reading discussions.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from bisect import bisect_right
import sys
from unittest.mock import right

class TrieNode(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.subnodes = {}
        self.isTerminal = False
        self.indexList = []
        self.healthList = []

    def addSubnode(self, aChar):
        if (self.subnodes.get(aChar)):
            return self.subnodes[aChar]
        else:
            newNode = TrieNode()
            self.subnodes[aChar] = newNode
            return newNode

    def addIndexAndValue(self, index, health):
        self.isTerminal = True
        self.indexList.append(index)
        lastHealth = 0
        healthLength = len(self.healthList)
        if (healthLength>0):
            lastHealth = self.healthList[healthLength-1]
        self.healthList.append(lastHealth + health)

    def getSubnodeFor(self, aChar):
        return self.subnodes.get(aChar)

    def getValueForIndexes(self, startIndex, endIndex):
        listSize = len(self.indexList)
        if listSize < 1:
            return 0
        elif listSize == 1:
            if startIndex <= self.indexList[0] and endIndex >= self.indexList[0]:
                return self.healthList[0]
            else:
                return 0 
        else: # listSize > 1  
            rightInd = bisect_left(self.indexList, endIndex)
            if rightInd < listSize and endIndex < self.indexList[0]:
                return 0

            big = 0

            if rightInd >= listSize:
                big = self.healthList[listSize - 1]
            else:
                if endIndex >= self.indexList[rightInd]:
                    big = self.healthList[rightInd]
                else:
                    big = self.healthList[rightInd-1]

            leftInd = bisect_left(self.indexList, startIndex)            

            small = 0
            if leftInd >= listSize:
                return 0
            else:
                if startIndex <= self.indexList[leftInd]:
                    if (leftInd > 0):
                        small = self.healthList[leftInd - 1]
                    else:
                        small = 0
                else:
                    small = self.healthList[leftInd]

            return big - small

class Trie(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()

    def getRoot(self):
        return self.root

    def createTrie(self, genes, healths):
        for i in range(len(genes)):
            node = self.root
            for c in genes[i]:
                node = node.addSubnode(c)
            node.addIndexAndValue(i, healths[i])


def calculateHealth(trie, d, first, last):
    total = 0
    dLength = len(d)
    for i in range(0, dLength):
        node = trie.getRoot()
        for j in range(i, dLength):
            node = node.getSubnodeFor(d[j])
            if node != None:
                if node.isTerminal:
                    val = node.getValueForIndexes(first, last)
                    total = total + val
            else:
                break 
    return total


def readFromFile(aFileName):

    inputArr = None
    with open('../hackerRank/src/' + aFileName, encoding='utf-8') as aFile:
        inputArr = aFile.read().splitlines()
    return inputArr


def runFor(fileName, minimumValue, maximumValue):
    inp = readFromFile(fileName)
    n = inp[0]
    genes = inp[1].rstrip().split()
    healths = list(map(int, inp[2].rstrip().split()))
    trie = Trie()
    trie.createTrie(genes, healths)
    s = int(inp[3])
    minVal = sys.maxsize
    maxVal = -1

    for fItr in range(s):
        line = inp[fItr+4].split()
        first = int(line[0])
        last = int(line[1])
        d = line[2]

        val = calculateHealth(trie, d, first, last)

        if val < minVal:
            minVal = val

        if val > maxVal:
            maxVal = val


    print (minVal,maxVal)
    assert minimumValue == minVal
    assert maximumValue == maxVal



# TextX.txt 's are simple text files, which hold test data for regarding test case
# following the file name are real expected numbers for each relevant test case
# I got those from hacker rank
runFor('Test2.txt', 15806635, 20688978289)
runFor('Test7.txt', 0, 7353994)
runFor('Test8.txt', 0, 8652768)
runFor('Test9.txt', 0, 9920592)
runFor('Test33.txt', 11674463, 11674463)
```

Comment: As they emphasize in the discussion, likely too much memory is used.

Comment: @user58697 Thank you for reply. As you pointed out, Hacker Rank expects solutions to run within a predefined memory size and within a predefined time slot. If any solution exceeds these expectations, it is supposed to give "Terminated due to timeout" error, not "Wrong Answer" message. Please refer to https://support.hackerrank.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014096954-The-Terminated-due-to-timeout-status-in-your-HackerRank-Tests. But am I 100% sure ? Not really :\ That's why I am asking this quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

One reference that might assist can be found at:
https://gist.github.com/josephmisiti/940cee03c97f031188ba7eac74d03a4f

Please read the notes he has included.

This is the input I have been using.

6
a b c aa d b
1 2 3 4 5 6
3
1 5 caaab
0 4 xyz
2 4 bcdybc